# TypeError: Object Is Not A Function (JavaScript Chrome Storage Sync)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

This is for accessing preferences saved in chrome.storage.sync using JavaScript for a Chrome Extension.

Code:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('allWeights', function(obj) {  
          allWeights = obj.allWeights();

          chrome.storage.sync.get('allIDs', function(obj2) { 
            allIDs = obj2.allIDs();
            alert("ALL WEIGHTS: " + allWeights);
            alert("ALL IDS: " + allIDs);
         });
    });
```

Error:

> Error in response to storage.get: TypeError: object is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument.restore_options

And the error is pointing to the first line (chrome.storage.sync.get('allWeights').

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is there a `chrome.storage.sync.set` taking place as well?

Comment: Yes, the setting is taking place in the "save_options()"  function and there are no bugs/errors/problems with saving

Comment: Yeah, but I believe the problem is in there. That is, the code `chrome.storage.sync.get('allWeights')` is returning an undefined\empty object. Which means using `get` on `'allWeights'` is the issue. This should be traced back to `set`. Can you Edit and provide the set as well? Or a link?

Comment: Because code in S.O. comments are difficult to read, here's the GitHub link: https://github.com/dsouzarc/powerSchoolGradeCalculator/blob/master/options.js 
I set the data at line 140

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: I did some searching, and I think the problem could be similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20476784/typeerror-object-is-not-a-function-node-js). It's a little tricky :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63815/discussion-between-ryan-dsouza-and-t-woody).

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: This works

```
 chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(items) {
        allWeights = items.allWeights;
        allIDs = items.allIDs;
        alert("ALL WEIGHTS: " + allWeights);
        alert("ALL IDS: " + allIDs);
    });
```

I had to change items.allWeights() to items.allWeights.

Apparently you can't access an object property with ()